# How to prevent exposing inheritance money in a trust in case of divorced?

Tags: real-estate, family-law, divorce

With inheritance money in a trust, if parents give us money for a house, will that expose all trust funds in a divorced in California?

Not worried about the "commingled" money given, only remaining balance in the trust. Asking if money from the trust is given for home purchase, will that expose the remaining balance of the trust to be split in a divorce settlement? If so how can money from trust be given without exposing remaining balance?

Comment: Without citing chapter and verse as I would in an answer, the mere existence of a trust is a highly significant factor in CA divorces to a greater degree in most other U.S. states.

Comment: You could try asking a lawyer to structure things to achieve your goals. In my experience, random yoohoos on the Internet are not very useful for estate-planning purposes.